# Spring Data / REST - Javascript (jquery, backbone) restful calls end up with a 404 response

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've got an example app: https://github.com/LateralThoughts/orsyp-frontend-training/tree/master/zupr_trackr.
It exposes 3 JPA entities ([Company](https://github.com/LateralThoughts/orsyp-frontend-training/blob/master/zupr_trackr/src/main/java/com/github/lateralthoughts/domain/Company.java), [Employee](https://github.com/LateralThoughts/orsyp-frontend-training/blob/master/zupr_trackr/src/main/java/com/github/lateralthoughts/domain/Employee.java), [Activity](https://github.com/LateralThoughts/orsyp-frontend-training/blob/master/zupr_trackr/src/main/java/com/github/lateralthoughts/domain/Activity.java)) via REST resources handled by Spring DATA/REST.

Although I can successfully query the REST API through a browser REST add-on for instance, the following query (on the same domain or another one) always returns a 404:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/companies/")
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function(event, jqxhr, exception) {
        console.log(jqxhr, exception);
    })
    .complete(function() { alert("Done"); }
);
```

The only difference we noticed while comparing a generated HTTP request (via a REST add-on) and a jquery-driven one is the absence of 'Referer' in the first case and its presence in the last.

Adding this header with the REST add-on interface will cause the request to fail as described earlier.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance

Rolf

P.S.: this is true for GET/POST and other verbs.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions on the Java side?  Is there a more detailed error message in the HTTP response?

Comment: It's not the last trailing / by any chance is it? happened to me before, you never know...

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, this is not about the trailing slash, both URL (with and without /) are both served when proceeding there manually.

I'll set LOG level to TRACE and see if I can detect any stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data REST doesn't like the `Accept` headers sent by jQuery.

jQuery sends these headers :

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

And if you try queries like this :

```
curl -v -XGET -H "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" http://localhost:8080/api/employees/
```

it will fail as a 404, but if you change it by removing the `text/javascript` part :

```
curl -v -XGET -H "Accept:application/json, */*; q=0.01" http://localhost:8080/api/employees/
```

this one works.

You can override the default `Accept` headers used by jQuery by using the `$.ajaxSetup` method, or you can simply override these settings when you query your API.

```js
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/api/employees", 
    accepts: {json:'application/json'}
})
```

Now about the **why**, I think there's a problem in Spring Data REST here :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.java#L46

where the `Accept` header is matched, and I think it may be due to the fact that `text/javascript` doesn't exists for SpringData REST.